# Word VBA For Each word replacement

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to find all words that start and end with the same character, and changing them. For now I want to just make them all say "foo".

```
For Each w In ActiveDocument.Words
    Dim startChar As String
    startChar = Left(w, 1)
    Dim endChar As String
    endChar = Right(w, 1)
    If UCase(startChar) = UCase(endChar) Then
        w = "foo"
    End If
Next w
```

If I do `Debug.Print` of `w`, I get the right result, but it's only in that scope--how do I get the word in the document to actually change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

w is a Word Range (and should ideally be declared as such), and although you can get its content using "w" because .Text is the "default member" of the Range object, to set it, you need something like

```
w.Text = "foo"
```

(Other points you will probably see when you explore further: the "end" of a Word will in some cases be the space after the Word, and the Word collection is dynamically altered as the text changes - in some cases it may make sense to replace your words starting at the end of the collection...

```
For i = ActiveDocument.Words.Count to 1 Step -1
' do your thing...
Next
```